# Receiving Multipart/form-data Response on client side (App side)

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to access file from Rest API using form data. In response I am receiving byte data along with header information. I need to extract byte data without header information

I can parse the data by splitting string by name or boundary name but it seems bad solution. Is there any other way to extract file?

```
byte[] content = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(content);
String S = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content, 0, content.Length);
var headerPlusData = S.Split(new string[] { "name=clipdata" },StringSplitOptions.None);
byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerPlusData[1]);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content);
```

Comment: what is the content? you want to find another better way to extract byte data without header information?

Comment: Content is basically binary file data which also has multipart header information, I want to separate both header and binary data. I am open to any better solution.